# Creating pivot table using vba - run time error

Tags: excel, pivot, vba

I am trying to create a pivot table using vba. Following is the code that i tried:

```
Sub CreatePivot()

    Dim objTable As PivotTable
    Dim objField As PivotField
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets.Add
    Sheets(ws.Name).Name = "Write-Off Pivot"

    ' Select the sheet and first cell of the table that contains the data.
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("GEP Write-Offs Rawdata").Select
    Range("A1").Select

    Set objTable = ws.PivotTableWizard

    ' Specify row and column fields.
    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("MPG")
    objField.Orientation = xlRowField

    ' Specify a data field with its summary
    ' function and format.
    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("'A_780610 - Inventory - Obsolescence")
    objField.Orientation = xlDataField
    objField.Function = xlSum
    objField.NumberFormat = "$ #,##0"


End Sub
```

I am getting this error message.
"Run-time error '104'"
"method 'pivottables' of object '_worksheet' failed"

The problem seems to be in this line but not able to figure what's causing it.

```
Set objTable = ws.PivotTableWizard
```

Comment: You seem to be missing some arguments.  Have a look at the formal documentation to see if it gets you any closer:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839228.aspx

Comment: @Yuvaraj I have submitted my answer after verification on test data with Excel 2016  and eager to have feedback from an active member like you. It is certainly not for points on answer but to enhance our learning experience as it is never ending process.

Comment: Your prompt action is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your following line needs change.

```
Set objTable = ws.PivotTableWizard
```

This should point to data source sheet. So it should be.

```
Set objTable = Sheets("GEP Write-Offs Rawdata").PivotTableWizard
```

It will make the pivot table and write in a new added sheet since your command

```
Set ws = Worksheets.Add
    Sheets(ws.Name).Name = "Write-Off Pivot"
```

is not linked to it.May please modify it suitably.

This is in addition to what @Rory suggested.

Comment: @Rory I gather courage to request your viewpoint on change suggested by me regarding Set objTable. Since I am at beginner level in excel-vba and eager to learn, I shall have no hesitation in withdrawing my answer if this is irrelevant or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Use `ActiveSheet.Pivottablewizard` rather than `ws.PivotTableWizard` since there isn't any data on the `ws` sheet.

Incidentally, this is unnecessarily convoluted:

```
Sheets(ws.Name).Name = "Write-Off Pivot"
```

All you need is:

```
ws.Name = "Write-Off Pivot"
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods PivotTableWizard needs some parameters:

Like this:

```
 Set objTable = ws.PivotTableWizard(xlDatabase, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Table8").Range("A1:A5"), ws.Range("A1:A6"))
```

There are a lot of parameters, for your example i needed the datasource type, the datasource and the datadestination.

You see all parameters if you just open the "(" after es.PivotTableWizard or you can get them here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff839228.aspx

Comment: It doesn't actually *need* any of them in fact.